# JB4A 4.9.7 Not Prompting for Location Permission

Tags: marketing-cloud

We're using JB4A 4.9.7 in our iOS app.  I am trying to enable the geofencing feature.  I haven't been able to get iOS to prompt for access to my location.  As I understand it, the SDK should handle this for me.

I have added entries to my plist for NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, NSLocationUsageDescription, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.

I am setting the andLocationServices parameter to YES when I configured the SDK:

```
        successful = [[ETPush pushManager] configureSDKWithAppID:kETAppID_Prod
                                          andAccessToken:kETAccessToken_Prod
                                           withAnalytics:YES
                                     andLocationServices:YES
                                    andProximityServices:NO
                                           andCloudPages:YES
                                         withPIAnalytics:YES
                                                   error:&error];
```

And I am calling startWatchingLocation method:

```
    ETLocationManager.sharedInstance().startWatchingLocation()
```

*Note: I am actually using Obj-C in one spot and Swift in another because our app has both*

I never see a prompt from iOS requesting permission to access location.  I am calling startWathingLocation later (after user logs in) and not on app launch, but I think that is "ok" from what I've read in the documentation.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the plist entries for location permission to include NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription to get the location prompt if they are running on iOS11. NSLocationUsageDescription should be removed.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.  I am now being prompted for permission to access location.  Thanks.